# Which Yagya To Perform When Wife Is Pregnant?

Tags: vedas, yajna

I’m deeply inspired with Vedic Dharma and Vedas. Agnihotra is what I found way to life.

There are many types of Yajna. So is there any Yajna which is best to perform for the benefits of child in the womb and the mother?

Comment: this combines scriptural question with personal advice. To answer personal advice part, you first have to qualify for doing yagnas. Are you a brahmin, did you have upanayana ceremony, do you wear sacred thread, do you perform daily anushtana ? if answer is no to any of above, then you can't do yagna yourself, but better get a purohit to help you out.

Comment: @Ram Ans is Yes!

Answer (score 2):

Putrakameshti Yagna is the preferred choice to perform during this time.

In the ancient Indian epic Ramayana, upon the recommendation of Sage Vashishta, King Dasharatha of Ayodhya performed the Putrakameshti Yajna under the supervision of Rishishringa Muni, who was an expert in Yajurveda, which has the guidelines for this prayer. After its successful completion, the Lord of Fire, Agnidev appeared and gave a bowl of sweet to the King of Ayodhya, which was provided to his three queens in order to promulgate his sons Sri Rama, Lakshmana, Bharata and Shatrughna.

Comment: Thank You For Your answer, But That Yagya was performed Before Pregnancy. My Q is Different.